# Flyout for autocomplete in WinUI 3 TextBox

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, winui-3

Can anyone explain what the ProofingMenuFlyout is for in WinUI 3 on a TextBox?
The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.proofingmenuflyout) for it is bare with no example on how to use it.

What I'm actually trying to do is create a popup menu much like the auto suggestion popup in the Visual Studio text editor that gives hints on methods etc. I.e. the one you can open with Ctrl+Space. I want this functionality inside a TextBox as a helper for when certain initial letters are written.

My initial though was to use some dynamic flyout that is opened from a TextChanged callback when a keyword is detected. Then I found this ProofingMenuFlyout that is rather undocumented and I can't figure out how to use, or what it is for.

Am I on the right track with using a menu flyout or should I consider some other way of doing it?

Comment: Is AutoSuggestBox inadequate?

Comment: AutoSuggestBox is for the whole full text of the TextBox, right? I only want certain key words that are being typed to show a suggestion box.

Comment: The Windows Community Toolkit's RichSuggestBox might do what you want. If you open the sample app and type character's like '@' or '#' you will see the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone explain what the ProofingMenuFlyout is for in WinUI 3 on a TextBox?

It is for spell checking.

[image]

Comment: I see, it is tied to the spell checking that is built into Windows, not something that you can dynamically provide yourself. I need to look more into using a ContextFlyout in my case then.